# Is there a way to link to strings.xml when a new string id is entered in an XML file in Android Studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio

If I'm adding a new item to a menu, say:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/numberOfColors"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:title="@string/choose_number" />
</menu>
```

The IDE complains that it `cannot resolve symbol "@string/choose_numer`.  So I open `strings.xml`, add the item, and the problem goes away.

Is it possible to enter a new value into `strings.xml` without having to open it and enter a new value?  A context menu option or something along those lines?

Comment: dup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778786/how-should-i-be-creating-strings-in-androidstudio-intellijidea

Answer (score 0):

Answer [here](http://envyandroid.com/archives/1111/android-studio-extract-strings-resources).

In short (for Windows):

> While developing apps, it might be easier to just hardcode the string
>   values, but when you are done testing, you can hit  ALT + Enter to
>   bring up the string resource extraction dialog.
>
> Choose Extract string resource, and type a name for the resource in
>   the dialog.
>
> Your string should now have been moved to the strings.xml file you
>   selected (default is in: values/strings.xml).